# How to create Advanced search in magento2.2.3.3.1?

Tags: magento2

how to create advanced search like amazon site, please check attached screenshot[enter link description here](https://nimb.ws/B2Na8x) if you have any custom code please share me.

Comment: Have you tried any third party plugins?
such as Amasty Advanced search to ensure you have a separate db for search?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156314)

Comment: there are lots of plugins and even every theme have built in such a functionality

Comment: i am not use any third party plugin. i want to make custom.

Comment: I am with Glenn Ryan.  We use the AMASTY elastic search and its brilliant and fast with elastic hosted on a different server